# Unable to Drop pglogical provider node

Tags: postgresql, pglogical

I am using pglogical in one of my production environments and I try to set up the subscriber node and its complaining of node interface not found. I decided to drop the provider node and recreate it again.
postgres=# select * from pglogical.node;

node_id   | node_name
------------+-----------
3171898924 | test_01

postgres=# SELECT pglogical.drop_node('test_01');
ERROR:  node interface 202885847 not found.

I also alter the node add node interface but its create a node interface with a different if_id

postgres=# select * from pglogical.node_interface ;
if_id    | if_name | if_nodeid  |                                if_dsn
------------+---------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
3043811503 | test_01   | 3171898924 |

I try dropping the entire node and recreate a new node since only one node can be created per database. It gives me the same error
SELECT pglogical.drop_node('test_01');
ERROR:  node interface 202885847 not found

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I've added node interface manually with the query:

```
   INSERT INTO pglogical.node_interface (if_id, if_name, if_nodeid, if_dsn)
   VALUES (OLD_INTERFACE_ID::oid, 'new name', NODE_ID::oid, 'dsn')
```

And then dropped the node with *pglogical.drop_node*